# Android: run sonarRunner from gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, android-build, sonar-runner

I'm stuck trying to get sonar reporting to run with an gradle Android project. Because most of the important sonar properties are only applied by the [sonarRunner gradle plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/sonar_runner_plugin.html) when the project is a `java` project I'm having trouble applying them for the `com.android.application` project.

This is my sonarRunner config:

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.profile", "Android Lint"
        property "sonar.sources", android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        property "sonar.binaries", file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/app") 
        property "sonar.libraries", "" // what to put here?
    }
}
```

The problem is, that sonar is complaining about classes not being found because the libraries could not be referenced.

How can the dependencies + android libraries being referenced in my sonarRunner configuration?

---

Example Error output:

```
INFO  - Load batch settings
INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\mannaz\.sonar\cache
INFO  - Install plugins
INFO  - Install JDBC driver
INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://sonar.local/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
INFO  - Load project settings
INFO  - Apply project exclusions
WARN  - 'sonar.dynamicAnalysis' is deprecated since version 4.3 and should no longer be used.
INFO  - -------------  Scan app
INFO  - Load module settings
INFO  - Loading technical debt model...
INFO  - Loading technical debt model done: 20 ms
INFO  - Loading rules...
INFO  - Loading rules done: 584 ms
INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2014-08-05)
INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2014-07-06, analysis of 2014-07-07 11:33:19.0)
INFO  - Compare to previous version (2014-07-21)
INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
INFO  - Base dir: C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\app
INFO  - Working dir: C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\app\build\sonar
INFO  - Source dirs: C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\app\src\main\java
INFO  - Binary dirs: C:\Users\mannaz\workspace\project\app\build\intermediates\classes\app
INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_AT
INFO  - Index files
INFO  - 197 files indexed
INFO  - Quality profile for java: Android Lint
INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
INFO  - 197 source files to be analyzed
ERROR - Class not found: android.widget.RelativeLayout
ERROR - Class not found: android.os.Handler
ERROR - Class not found: android.content.Context
ERROR - Class not found: android.app.Activity
ERROR - Class not found: android.util.AttributeSet
ERROR - Class not found: android.view.View
ERROR - Class not found: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions
ERROR - Class not found: com.google.gson.Gson
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which works for my multi-project Gradle build:

```
subprojects.each { p ->
    sonarRunner {
        sonarProperties {
            // ... some settings omitted ...
            property p.name + '.sonar.java.binaries', p.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
            property p.name + '.sonar.java.libraries', p.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.filter { File f -> f.exists() }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that

1. I use the test runtime classpath libraries, because we have a providedCompile scope which would not be considered in the main runtime classpath.
2. The sonar-runner complains if the libraries setting contains directories which don't exist (e.g. because a module doesn't have src/main/resources)
3. `sonar.java.libraries` is used, because it doesn't work with `sonar.libraries` for me.

Comment: > `p.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.filter { File f -> f.exists() }`

Why looking at the test classpath? I assume that the libraries in this case should be third party libraries?

Comment: @Alix This relates to my 1st remark below the source code - it's because I have dependencies in providedCompile scope, which do not belong to the main runtime classpath (because they are present on the target system), but do belong to the test runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to set your library property manually with the correct configuration. Something like this:

```
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.profile", "Android Lint"
        property "sonar.sources", android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
        property "sonar.binaries", file("${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/app") 
        property "sonar.libraries", "android.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath"
    }
}
```

Or what ever your correct dependency configuration is the right one.

Comment: `Or what ever your correct dependency configuration is the right one.` Thats exactly what I want to know: Whats the correct dependency configuration?

Comment: Ok I am not that experienced with android. But usually the default is `runtime` or `compile`. Either way it should be defined in your dependencies block, isn't it? In worst case just iterate over 'project.dependecies' and add every configuration ;-)

Comment: Did you find out what should be here? 
property "sonar.libraries", "" // what to put here?

I have the same problem, and this doesnt work:
property "sonar.libraries", "android.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath"